# Cannot bundle update --bundler in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

I have installed 3.0.0 of Ruby on Ubuntu in my project but I am trying to bundle install and it is giving me the following error.

```
ruby_dep-1.5.0 requires ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2, which is incompatible
with the current version, ruby 3.0.0p0
```

This is a project which I have cloned from another machine previously and now trying to open it on this new machine.

Comment: The error message says it all: You have dependency that, for whatever reason, has locked the ruby version to `2.x`. You have a few options: (1) Update the dependency version; someone might have already relaxed the version constraint (and updated anything else if needed). (2) Update the dependency yourself; fork the project and update it. (3) Remove the dependency. Maybe it was only used for something small an unimportant. (4) Just use ruby v2.x for now, at least on this project. (5) Sit back and wait for someone to resolve (1) for you. It might take days, weeks, months, years, or never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ruby_dep](https://github.com/e2/ruby_dep) has not been updated in since 2016 and looks abandoned. As suggested by the comment (3) remove ruby_dep from your Gemfile and see how well bundler handles it, otherwise fork or raise an issue at the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error. I removed the ruby_dep-1.5.0 and ran bundle install again. Then I got this other error:

> Blockquote

listen-3.1.5 requires ruby version >= 2.2.3

I simply deleted the Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install and everything went smoothly with a new Gemfile.lock.